# Conditional breakpoint with trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I have what I think is a stack corruption.
I have an stack variable (a pointer ) in the position:
0x7000C0E4 ; the normal information stored is 0x700022A5

I know that from time to time some unexpected code trashes  the high part of the word getting one of these values:

0x000022A5 or 0x005122A5; I guess is a 16 bits write operation.

I'd like to set a breakpoint to stop when someone writes in that address but only when after the write the content of the stack address is 0x000022A5 or 0x005122A5

I guess I need two conditional breakpoints.
Anyone knows idf this is possible and the syntax to setup such breakpoints.

After @Holger comments I've setup what I think is the conditional breakpoint I need. But it does not work as expected. See he attached picture. Let me recall:
 I know someone is corruption the 0x7000c0de position, writing a 0x0000 instead of the expected value 0x7000. I use that as a pointer and the resulted pointer is 0x000022A5 instead of the expected 0x700022A5. I've setup 2 breakpoints , one at the trap function (I fall here after trying to access to the bad address) and a conditional Write breakpoint which should stop only when some writes the 0x0000 and additionaly the 0x7000c0dc address content is 0x000022A5. As you see in the picture my debugger stops only in the TRap function and at that moment the content of the 0x7000c0dc is effectively 0x000022A5. So why this conditional breakpoint is not working?
[image]

Comment: I guess the conditional data breakpoint from your screenshot is either not working, because the data was not written by the CPU or it was not a 16-bit write to the upper 16-bits as you've expected. Maybe try it with a data breakpoint with the address aligned to 32-bits and the 32-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done with data breakpoints.

The command in TRACE32 for data breakpoints is this one:
   Break.Set *<address>* /Write /Data.*<width>* *<value>*

In your particular case you'll need two data-breakpoints. E.g. like this:

```
Break.Set 0x7000C0E6 /Write /Data.Word 0x0000  
Break.Set 0x7000C0E6 /Write /Data.Word 0x0051
```

This will only work if your CPU supports data breakpoints and if the change on the stack was actually done by the CPU. It will not stop if the memory was altered by DMA or a peripheral hardware component or so.

If your CPU does not support data breakpoints TRACE32 will emulate the data breakpoints in a way that it will actually stop every time data is written to the given address, but immediately restart the CPU if the written data does not match.

Comment: ok thanks @Holger. What about the condition? This is a stack location, so they might be many _modules_ writing here, I'd like to stop the CPU only when after that write the 0x7000c0e4 content is 0x000022A5 or 0x005122A5

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you don't understand in my answer. Or maybe I don't get the problem. But I think the data breakpoint is what you need (and not the conditional breakpoint): The **address** ot the data breakpoint is the *data* address (and *not* a program address). So in you case 0x7000c0e4 or (as I wrote before) 0x7000C0E6 if you are only interested in a 16-bit write to the upper 16-bit. And the **value** is the data value, which should also match. So in you case 0x000022A5. Deeding on your CPU you have to know if the bad access is a 16-bit or 32-bit access.

Comment: A conditional breakpoint is probably not what you want because it is always intrusive: Which means your core is always stopped at address 0x7000c0e4 and only immediately restarted after the condition was checked and failed. Intrusive breakpoints can make your application *a lot* slower.

Comment: Keep in mind that changes in your memory not performed by your CPU can not be found with any read/write breakpoint.

Comment: To understand all the options of the breakpoints in TRACE32 I recommend to read the chapter about Breakpoints in "Debugger Basics - Training" (https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/training_debugger.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Holger, yes, I do understand your initial answer, I was just pointing out that in addition to the stop when writing I needed also a condition, since I only want to stop when the address holds that corrupted value. If I leave a simpler breakpoint at every write to 0 the CPU is continuously stoping since that address belongs to the stack and is continuosly used and written. on the other hand I also suspected about some DMA , but is curious that only 16 bits seem to be corrupted. If a DMA were the cause I guess i would see much more bytes corrupted around.